# Can a fragment implement two interfaces from its parent activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

In order to communicate between fragments we use an interface pattern that the parent activity implements... just like in the docs for example a fragment can get the parent interface on its attachment to the activity.

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

...
}
```

But say for example the parent activity implements another interface

```
public interface OnThreadCliked{
    void onThreadClicked(Post post);
}
```

Is there a way to get the reference to a second interface that activity implements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just cast it twice:

```
OnThreadCliked mCallback2;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the second callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback2 = (OnThreadCliked) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnThreadCliked");
    }
}
```